# Storing input values in structs for fastest comparison later

Tags: c, embedded, pic, microprocessors

I'm sampling eight input ports and comparing the values up to ten times a second.

These inputs will be XOR'd against a similar field, indicating which signals are set to "Active Low", then an AND operation to mask out input signals that are not going to be compared (though all signals are sampled, whether compared or not).

So this is an example for the sampling. I've created a struct where the signals will be stored and then saved in memory. This struct contains a lot of other values, so replacing the whole struct is not an option. Anyway, these input values need to be saved in a efficient way so I later on can perform fast XOR and AND operations with my masks.

```
void SampleData(){
   // These are not all values o be sampled, only inputs
   currentSample.i0       = RD13_bit;
   currentSample.i1       = RD12;
   currentSample.i2       = RD11;
   currentSample.i3       = RD10;
   currentSample.i4       = RE12;
   currentSample.i5       = RE13;
   currentSample.i6       = RF8;
   currentSample.i7       = RF9;
}
```

This is an example of the comparison I need

```
checkInputSignals(){
  activated = ((inputValues ^ activeLowInputs) & activeInputsMask);  

  if(activated ){
    importantMethod();
  }

 }
```

I've tried a bitfield, but I couldn't get the operators to work, and I've no knowledge about the effiency using bitfield. Efficiency in this project is not focused on memory, but speed and comfort. How should I store my three fields? If it helps, I am using a dsPic33EP microprocessor.

If using a 'char' or 'uint_8', my sample method would look like this, right? And this does not seem to be the most elegant solution.

```
    unsigned char inputValues;

    void SampleData(){
       currentSample.i0       = RD13_bit;
       currentSample.i1       = RD12;
       currentSample.i2       = RD11;
       currentSample.i3       = RD10;
       currentSample.i4       = RE12;
       currentSample.i5       = RE13;
       currentSample.i6       = RF8;
       currentSample.i7       = RF9;
       // For the masking
       inputValues += currentSample.i7;
       inputValues  = (inputValues << 1) + currentSample.i6;
       inputValues  = (inputValues << 1) + currentSample.i5;
       inputValues  = (inputValues << 1) + currentSample.i4;
       inputValues  = (inputValues << 1) + currentSample.i3;
       inputValues  = (inputValues << 1) + currentSample.i2;
       inputValues  = (inputValues << 1) + currentSample.i1;
       inputValues  = (inputValues << 1) + currentSample.i0;
    }
```

And I would have to do the same for my masks, for example.

```
void ConfigureActiveLowInputs(){
  activeLowInputs += currentCalibration->I0_activeLow;
  activeLowInputs  = (activeLowInputs << 1) + currentCalibration->I1_activeLow;
  activeLowInputs  = (activeLowInputs << 1) + currentCalibration->I2_activeLow;
  activeLowInputs  = (activeLowInputs << 1) + currentCalibration->I3_activeLow;
  activeLowInputs  = (activeLowInputs << 1) + currentCalibration->I4_activeLow;
  activeLowInputs  = (activeLowInputs << 1) + currentCalibration->I5_activeLow;
  activeLowInputs  = (activeLowInputs << 1) + currentCalibration->I6_activeLow;
  activeLowInputs  = (activeLowInputs << 1) + currentCalibration->I7_activeLow;
}
```

There must be a better solution than bit shifting?

Comment: Saving 8 bits is generally done using an `uint8_t`. If that's not what you are searching for, then ask your question more clearly.

Comment: But using 'uint8_t' or 'char' im facing many shift operations to get my inputs into 'inputValues', and i need to do the same for my masks.

Comment: You should use bitwise-OR (`|`) rather than addition (`+`).

Comment: 10 samples per second is rather low and is hardly *necessitates* efficiency - though efficiency is not a bad aim in any case.  With respect to "efficiency", are we talking about memory usage, code size or execution speed?

Comment: @Clifford, That's 10 thousand samples per second, I believe.

Comment: @JoshCaswell : If that is the case, it is inconsistent with "1.0".  Given the cultural ambiguities, it is best not to use thousand separators at all.

Comment: Good point, @Clifford. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Some things I think you need to know.

1. Don't use bit fields. Apart from being non-portable, they make this kind of bit-twiddling harder, not easier.
2. Don't use run-time shifts. Get the compiler to do your work.
3. Do read code, study and practice. Learning bit-twiddling can be hard, and from your code I don't think you're quite there yet.

If we're going to help there are some things we need to know.

- You mention 8 ports. Are they single bit ports, or single ports with multiple bits?
- You mention 3 fields. What are they?
- Your sample code uses `+` operators, which are rarely used in bit operations. Why?

In C the code usually ends up with a set of macros and defines, plus a few small functions. It's all quite simple, generates good code, and runs fast without too much effort. If we only knew what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be storing individual bits is separate structure members, and then packing them to word on the fly to be able to apply masks; but it is probably more efficient to pack them into a word, and use a mask to access the individual bits when necessary.

The members `i0`, `i1` etc. are probably unnecessary. It would be simpler to pack the bits directly into a `uint8_t` member, then write functions or macros to return individual bits where necessary.

```
uint8_t void SampleData()
{
    return (RD13_bit << 7 ) |
           (RD12 << 6) |
           (RD11 << 5) |
           (RD10 << 4) |
           (RE12 << 3) |
           (RE13 << 2) |
           (RF8 << 1) |
           RF9 ;
}
```

Then:

```
currentSample.i = SampleData() ;
```

Then you can apply masks to that directly. If you need to access individual bits (and if you don't, why make then separate members in the first case?) then for example:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#define GETBIT( word, bit ) (((word) & (1<<bit) != 0)


bool i6 = GETBIT( currentSample.i, 6 ) ;
```

Comment: Wouldn't `((word) >> (bit)) & 1` make more sense? Is there a reason I'm missing for doing it the other way or is the logical compare existing to put it into proper `bool` form?

Comment: @rjp I don't know about "more sense"; personal choice and style perhaps. I chose to represent the bit as a book. If you choose to represent it as an int, yours is appropriate.